# Dart: Why does the add method on colors not work? why don't you add orange to me?

Tags: flutter, dictionary, dart, set

Dart: Why does the add method on colors not work? why don't you add orange to me?

```
Set<String> colors = {"yellow", "red"};
colors.add("orange");
print(colors);
```

Comment: Your code should work. What is the error you are getting? What is the behavior you are expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
void main() {
  Set<String> colors = {"yellow", "red"};
  colors.add("orange");
  print(colors);
}
```

prints the following to the console:

> {yellow, red, orange}

If it does not for you, you may want to reinstall.